# Check which files [dict] match with given path

Tags: python, dictionary, directory, path

I have a dict with files:

```
files = {
    "/test/path/file1.c": "NotImportant",
    "/test/path/file2.c": "NotImportant",
    "/other/path/filex.c": "NotImportant",
    "/different/path/filez.c": "NotImportant"
    }
```

I now have a dict e.g. `path = '/test/path/'` and I want to see which file is in this specific path.
I tried it with

```
if path in files:
    print("found")
```

However this is not working for me. I solved it with a loop going through every file and checking with the same statement. Is there still another way to solve it?

My solution:

```
for file in files:
    if path in file:
        print("found")
```

Why does the statement work here and not before? I want to have a better solution instead of looping over the whole files.

Comment: None of the "dicts" you have is actually a dict. The first one is a set (but with missing commas), the second is a string

Comment: Was just for demonstration (shouldn't be the implementation), so you know what I mean. I'm still working with a dict.

Comment: See [ask] and provide [mcve]. We don't know what you mean, you have to show us

Comment: The first statement does not work because you are looking for `'/test/path/'` inside the set of files, and in your second statement, you are looking inside the objects within the set.

Comment: How do I check which files are in my given path. Thats my question

Comment: You could reorganize your data to make it look like a tree like `files = { 'test': { 'path': ['file1.c', 'file2.c'] }, 'other': {'path': ['filex.c'] }, 'different': {'path': ['filez.c'] } }`

Comment: I updated the question know, so maybe its a bit more clear. I tried it with files.keys() shouldn't that work? My file should be the key or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you regular expression to match path.

for example:

```
path_pattern = "^{}/.*".format(path)
for file in files:
    if re.match(path_pattern, file):
        print("Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by DeepSpace: none of your elements are dictionaries.

Your first element is indeed a set and the second is simply a string whereas a Python dictionary is a list of key associated to values (like a word is associated to a definition in a real dictionary).

Second, the way to go is the best practice to do it: you have to look at the path name of each file in files to check if path = '/test/path/' is present in each of these files.

Just like a human would do!

So that's the good way to do it!

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. I thought I'm missing something on how to check that. Looping was kind of a "bad" solution for me.